# Cargar Tabla con registros de archivo Excel convertido a JSON

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, html5, datatables

intento cargar una tabla con registros formato JSON convertidos desde Excel, revisando en console me esta marcando un error: ReferenceError: document is not defined at Object.
No se si es un problema de librería o algún complemento que falta.
Particularmente encuentro muy poca información de los tutoriales con respecto a importar Excel para transformarlo a formato JSON y cargar una tabla o DataTable con Java Script
Aquí les dejo el código para que me puedan indicar donde esta el error.

Saludos.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">
    <div class="container py-4">
      <div class="row mb-4"> 
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="excel-input">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div class= "row">
      </div class="col-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="excel-table">
          <!-- <tbody>-->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!--nombre, pais, salario, rol-->
                </tr>
            </thead>
           </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--  Biblioteca para excel read-excelfile -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
         
 <!--  Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script> 
   
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js     Java Script

```
class Excel{
    constructor(content){
        this.content = content
    }

    header(){
        return this.content[0]
    }

    rows(){
        return new RowCollection(this.content.slice(1, this.content.length))
    }
}

class RowCollection{
    constructor(rows){
        this.rows=rows
    }

    first(){
        return new Row(this.rows[0])
    }

    get(index){
        return new Row(this.rows[index])
    }

    count(){
        return this.rows.length
    }

    whereCountry (countryName){
        
    }
}   

class Row{
    constructor(row){
        this.row=row
    }

    name(){
        return this.row[0]
    }

    country(){
        return this.row[1]
    }

    salary(){
        return this.row[3]
    }

    role(){
        return this.row[2]
    }
}

class ExcelPrinter{
    static print(tableId,excel){
        const table = document.getElementById(tableId)
        excel.header().forEach(title => {
            table.querySelector("thead>tr").innerHTML+=`<td>${title}</td>`
        })

        for (let index=0;index < excel.rows().count();index++){ 
            const row = excel.rows().get(index); 
            table.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML+= `
                 <tr>
                 <td>${row.name()}</td>
                 <td>${row.country()}</td>
                 <td>${row.role()}</td>
                 <td>${row.salary()}</td>
              </tr>   
            `
        }

    }

}

const excelInput = document.getElementById('excel-input')
excelInput.addEventListener('change', async function(){
     const content = await readXlsxFile(excelInput.files[0])
     const excel = new Excel(content)

     //console.log(excel.rows().first())
})
```

Comment: Tienes errores en tu HTML `</tbody>` no tiene la etiqueta de inicio `</div class= "row"></div class="col-12">` tienen formato de cierre con el `/`, pero claramente son de inicio

Comment: Por otro lado, no entiendo que tiene que ver tu pregunta con JSON y Datatables, tu código no tiene nada de eso

Comment: Efectivamente me equivoque en plantear la consulta, no tiene que ver con DataTable ni JSON.  En este caso es para LEER un archivo Excel y mostrarlo en una TABLA de html. Estoy usando una librería read-excel-file pero aun no logro conseguir mostrarlo en la tabla, me marca error:  ReferenceError: document is not defined at Object.       Gracias

Comment: Yo probé tu código, realizando las correcciones que te indico en mi primer comentario, y no me da error alguno

Comment: Corregí lo que mencionaste, pero aun no me logra pintar la tabla html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios, si tu:

- Agregas la etiqueta de apertura del `<tbody>` que te falta
- A los `</div class= "row"></div class="col-12">` le quitas la barra `/` que sobran
- Y por supuesto, llamas a la función que crea la tabla `ExcelPrinter.print("excel-table",excel)`

Funciona correctamente

```js
class Excel{
    constructor(content){
        this.content = content
    }

    header(){
        return this.content[0]
    }

    rows(){
        return new RowCollection(this.content.slice(1, this.content.length))
    }
}

class RowCollection{
    constructor(rows){
        this.rows=rows
    }

    first(){
        return new Row(this.rows[0])
    }

    get(index){
        return new Row(this.rows[index])
    }

    count(){
        return this.rows.length
    }

    whereCountry (countryName){
        
    }
}   

class Row{
    constructor(row){
        this.row=row
    }

    name(){
        return this.row[0]
    }

    country(){
        return this.row[1]
    }

    salary(){
        return this.row[3]
    }

    role(){
        return this.row[2]
    }
}

class ExcelPrinter{
    static print(tableId,excel){
        const table = document.getElementById(tableId)
        excel.header().forEach(title => {
            table.querySelector("thead>tr").innerHTML+=`<td>${title}</td>`
        })

        for (let index=0;index < excel.rows().count();index++){ 
            const row = excel.rows().get(index); 
            table.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML+= `
                 <tr>
                 <td>${row.name()}</td>
                 <td>${row.country()}</td>
                 <td>${row.role()}</td>
                 <td>${row.salary()}</td>
              </tr>   
            `
        }

    }

}

const excelInput = document.getElementById('excel-input')
excelInput.addEventListener('change', async function(){
     const content = await readXlsxFile(excelInput.files[0])
     const excel = new Excel(content)

     ExcelPrinter.print("excel-table",excel)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">
    <div class="container py-4">
      <div class="row mb-4"> 
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="excel-input">

        </div>
      </div>
    <div class= "row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="excel-table">
          <!-- <tbody>-->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!--nombre, pais, salario, rol-->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--  Biblioteca para excel read-excelfile -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
         
 <!--  Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script> 
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si, me faltaba:  ExcelPrinter.print("excel-table",excel).   Ahora solo me queda tratar de adaptarlo a un DataTable o armar una tabla HTML mas completa.    Muchas gracias estimado!

Comment: @JuanAlberto muchas gracias ?= votar positivo? Marcar como aceptada?